# how do I get maximize attribute from tkinter window?

Tags: python

I want to see if the user has maximized a tkinter window by checking for a boolean true or false.

`check = Window.cget('fullscreen')` doesn't work.

Is there a way?

Comment: What "doesn't work" about it? Does it do nothing? Make an error? Crash your computer? Make flying monkeys fall from the sky? Give you free waffles? Please clarify.

Comment: i get 'unknown option "-fullscreen".   and 2 free waffles.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

```
root = Tk()
root.attributes('-zoomed', True)
```

Or:

```
root.state('zoomed')
```

The second option will not show a title bar